# Using dc-app-performance-toolkit with Taurus on windows

Tags: jira, performance-testing, taurus

I am trying to use https://github.com/atlassian/dc-app-performance-toolkit on windows 10

I have installed taurus from https://gettaurus.org/install/Installation/

jira is installed on my system and i can access it using http://localhost:2990/jira

However when i run **bzt jira.yml** i am getting below error.

```
14:43:35 INFO: Starting shell command: python util/post_run/jmeter_post_check.py←[0m
14:43:36 INFO: Starting shell command: python util/jtl_convertor/jtls-to-csv.py kpi.jtl selenium.jtl←[0m
←[33m14:43:36 WARNING: Errors for python util/jtl_convertor/jtls-to-csv.py kpi.jtl selenium.jtl:
Traceback (most recent call last):



File "util/jtl_convertor/jtls-to-csv.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\numpy\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
←[0m
←[31m14:43:36 ERROR: Child Process Error: Test runner selenium (PyTestExecutor) has failed with retcode 1←[0m
←[31m14:43:36 ERROR: PyTestExecutor STDERR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\bzt\resources\pytest_runner.py", line 22, in <module>
    import pytest
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\pytest\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import register_assert_rewrite
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\_pytest\assertion\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import rewrite
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 30, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import util
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\_pytest\assertion\util.py", line 14, in <module>
    import _pytest._code
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\_pytest\_code\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .code import Code
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\_pytest\_code\code.py", line 29, in <module>
    import pluggy
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\pluggy\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .manager import PluginManager, PluginValidationError
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\pluggy\manager.py", line 11, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 623, in <module>
    __version__ = version(__name__)
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 585, in version
    return distribution(distribution_name).version
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 558, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Taurus\pkgs\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 215, in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
importlib_metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for importlib_metadata←[0m
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is about missing [importlib-metadata](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/) package, you need to have all the packages listed under [requirements.txt](https://github.com/atlassian/dc-app-performance-toolkit/blob/master/requirements.txt) installed in order to be able to run these tests, it seems like you omitted [Installation and set up](https://github.com/atlassian/dc-app-performance-toolkit#installation-and-set-up) chapter

So make sure to execute `pip install -r requirements.txt` prior to launching the Taurus test as Taurus doesn't take care of dependencies on its own.

More information:

- [Installing Python Package Dependencies](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Cloud/#Installing-Python-Package-Dependencies)
- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove python installed at
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\

which was installed prior to bzt

To correct this, I have uninstalled taurus and installed it manually.

Installed python using python-3.8.5-amd64.exe. and not using python-3.8.5.exe